# Sparkleformation: No output received from `sfn print`

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to try out sparkle formation following the [documentation](http://www.sparkleformation.io/docs/guides/getting-started.html#create-a-template), but I do not receive any output from the command `bundle exec sfn print --file compute`. I have also tried different paths to my compute file with no change. I would like to view the template cloudformation json that this is supposed to create.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide is somewhat incomplete and I needed to add a name for my stack and the exact path to the template file into the command: `bundle exec sfn print my-stack-name --file sparkleformation/compute.rb`